# How can I get the version of the pgrep & pkill commands?

Tags: process, utilities, version

I looked at the manpages and there is no `-v` or `--version` argument for pgrep or pkill. How can i get some info on the version?

I'm asking because on my version of Ubuntu man `pgrep` is giving me a different manual then on my server. Ideally I would install the same version on my machine too.

Comment: Did you try `-V` ? :)

Comment: that is the only one i didn't try, and it's not even listed in the manual!! aaargh... post it as a answer and i'll mark it as the solution :D

Comment: It's not? What system are you on? It's documented quite clearly on my Debian. It's the penultimate option mentioned, just above `-h`.

Comment: @Gabriel glad you solved it. `-V, --version` is mentioned in the `man pgrep` or `man pkill`

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS ... output of `pgrep -V` is `pgrep (procps version 3.2.8)` and for real it's not listed in `man pgrep` you can find it here http://pastebin.com/WDpfsuJr

Comment: val0x00ff look at my pastebin :D there is no mention of -V or --version

Comment: Huh, that's a bug in Ubuntu then. It is listed in the man pages on Debian (well, LMDE at least) and Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: i checked it in ubuntu 13.10 and it's listed there, i'll look at procps 3.2.8 if it's missing from the source code too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it by typing capital V instead of small v:

```
$ pgrep -V
pgrep from procps-ng 3.3.3
$ pkill -V
pkill from procps-ng 3.3.4
```

Comment: weird thing is, it's not listed in `man pgrep` ...

Comment: @Gabriel The beauty of Open Source, is you can actually add this to the manpage for that project if you are so inclined :)

Comment: i would do that if i knew how to do that :D maybe i'll look into it

Comment: This does not work on macOS. `/usr/bin/pgrep: illegal option -- V`

Answer (score 5):

To get some version information, find `pgrep` in your `PATH` and run the command `what`. I get:

```
% what /usr/bin/pgrep
/usr/bin/pgrep
    PROGRAM:pkill  PROJECT:adv_cmds-149
```

Note that the program name is `pkill`. `pkill` and `pgrep` are hard links to the same binary on my system (OS X).

Explanation (from the manual):

> NAME
>        what -- show what versions of object modules were used to construct a file
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        what reads each file name and searches for sequences of the form "@(#)",
>        as inserted by the source code control system.  It prints the remainder of the 
>        string following this marker, up to a null character, newline, double quote, 
>        or "> character."

PS. `pgrep` does not accept the `-v` or `-V` flag on my system (OS X), so looking at version strings is the only option.

Comment: But where's the version string in the output you show? Also, `what` seems to be an OSX (BSD?) command, I can't find or install it on my Debian.

Comment: `what` is an ancient BSD command-- I remember it from literally over a decade ago. I didn't even know OS X had it until I tried. The code group and version is `adv_cmds-149` -- obviously not the release tag you were looking for, but that's apparently not embedded in the OS X version.

Comment: Huh, OK. But according to the `man` page, that would be the version the `object modules were used to construct a file`, not the version of the `pgrep` itself then but of the libraries used to compile it right?

Comment: Object modules (`.o`) are compiled code, typically C code. `main()` lives in an object module too. A program may link together several object modules, _some_ of them from libraries. The version you see with `-V` must be defined in one of the object files too -- but it's made accessible from the command line.